# Where did my directory go after "mv parentdir/mydir ../mydir"?

Tags: linux, command-line

I thought I was moving a sub directory up a level so that it would be a sibling of its parent.   But it's now completely invisible.   Is it gone?

Here's the command I used:

```
mv parentdir/mydir ../mydir
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.   All I did was change the name so that it started with the .., and that made it hidden to the "ls" command.

Comment: Ah.... so you accidentally ran "mv parentdir/mydir ..mydir" not "mv parentdir/mydir ../mydir"  (no slash after the dots) I'll guess.  Good find!  Thanks for updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

If `../mydir` already existed, you've moved it into `../mydir/mydir`.  Otherwise it's at `../mydir`.

In a command like this, paths are relative to the current working directory (unless the path starts with `/`, in which case it's an absolute path).  So your command didn't tell `mv` to make `mydir` a sibling of `parentdir`, you told it to make `mydir` a sibling of the working directory.

What you wanted to do was one of these two:

```
# make parentdir/mydir to be a sibling of parentdir
$ mv parentdir/mydir ./
$ ls -1
parentdir
mydir

# make parentdir/mydir to be a sibling of parentdir
$ ( cd parentdir ; mv mydir ../ )
$ ls -1
parentdir
mydir
```

Answer (score 0):

When running a command like `cp`, `scp`, `mv` and the like, where the second argument is a directory, it's safest to end it with a `/.`, so that both you and the command know that you are looking for a directory there.  For example, instead of doing this:

```
$ mv /opt/foo /temp
```

I would do:

```
$ mv /opt/foo /temp/.
```

and get the error message:

```
mv: cannot move `/opt/foo' to `/temp/.': No such file or directory
```

because, of course, I meant to type `/tmp/.`. Had I run the first command I would have silently -- and quite unintentionally -- renamed the directory.